# GUI for single interface approach

Tags: c#, user-interface

I've made a small application using MDI but I want to make another one where there is only one main window and the main container changes or updates. I'm sure this can be done without creating multiple panels but I've been doing a bit of reading and I can't seem to find how can I do this.

Comment: what about using a tabControl (although it contains of panels too)

Comment: I'm sorry but I find it difficult to visualise what your trying to do. Also do you want to have both UI's in the same application? Could edit your question to clarify it a little, and tell us a little more about what you're trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't too clear about my question. I'm a bit new in this Winform programming and I've never used UserControls but after a few articles I think this what I was looking for. Cheers for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to keep only one form. You can use tab control and switch between different pages, or create a set of user controls and then manage yourself what user control to show

Comment: thanks for the reply. After a few articles and tutorials, I realized that User controls is the way to go. Design multiple UserControls and use a Panel as the parent right?

Comment: @ratio_nz yes, you can design your form with some basic layout where you will have panels or whatever container you need and place user controls there

Answer (score 0):

For my scrum information radiator (full screen application for a big TV in portrait) I decided to use a set of controls from Actipro. I have multiple windows, but only one visible at a time. The user can use the arrow keys to "swipe" windows in and out just like they're used to do in smartphones.

The control used was the ZapPanel, as seen in my xaml below:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False" SelectionMode="Single" 
             SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="Black">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <views:ZapPanel AreChildrenWrapped="True" Orientation="Horizontal" AreLeavingElementsAnimated="True" Background="Black" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0.5" >
        <Button Click="PrevButtonClick">Prev</Button>
        <Button Click="NextButtonClick">Next</Button>
    </StackPanel>



</Grid>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Which exact controls did you use? I don't have the cash to purchase any expensive controls so could this be done with the toolbox Visual Studio provides?